Google Sheets Absolute Reference not locking to a cell
I have this formula
=CHOOSEROWS(SORT('Sheet1'!$C$1:H627,RANDARRAY(ROWS('Sheet1'!$C$1:H627)),1),SEQUENCE(2))

Which is working great, however when I insert a new row at the top and cell reference in the formula moves to $C$2 when it should stay at $C$1, how do I fix this?

Use INDIRECT:
=LET(r,INDIRECT("Sheet1!C1:H"&ROW(Sheet1!H627)),SORTN(r,2,,RANDARRAY(ROWS(r)),1))


I got an error - Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'Sheet1!C1:H627'. It is not a valid cell/range reference. I also need it to still chooserows, sort and sequence

did you change Sheet1 to match with your sheet's name?

=LET(r,INDIRECT('Sheet1'!C1:H&ROW('Sheet1'!H627)),CHOOSEROWS(SORT(r,RANDARRAY(ROWS(r)),1)),SEQUENCE(2))  when I tried to merge the 2 together - formula parse error

you don't need SORT and CHOOSEROWS/SEQUENCE if you just want to pick n random values. You can simply use SORTN.

=LET(r,INDIRECT('Sheet 1'!C1:H&ROW('Sheet 1'!H627)),SORTN(r,2,,RANDARRAY(ROWS(r)),1))  - A matching value could not be found. To get the values for the entire range use the ARRAYFORMULA function.

that's not the same formula I provided. Please double check.

=LET(r,INDIRECT("Sheet 1!C1:H"&ROW(Sheet 1!H627)),SORTN(r,2,,RANDARRAY(ROWS(r)),1)) - formula parse error

replace Sheet 1 with 'Sheet 1'
